# Python :string index out of range with trying to find first capital letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, recursion

I am trying to get the first capital letter in the string but I am getting an `index out of range error`  I don't know if it is my base case for the recursion. Please can someone help me

This is my code:

```
def firstCapital(str, i):
    if (str[i] == None):
        return 0
    if (str[i].isupper()):
        return str[i]
    return firstCapital(str, i + 1)

name = "geoRge"
res = firstCapital(name, 0)
if (res == 0):
    print("No uppercase letter")
else:
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (str[i] == None):` doesn't do what you want it to do. This seems like it's trying to check if your index is off the end of the string, but strings in Python don't have `None` after the last real character. Rather, you get exactly the exception you describe when you try to index past the end.

Instead, you should be comparing `i` to `len(str)`, which is the length of the string as a number. Since indexes start at zero, an index equal to `len(str)` is just past the end, so you probably want:

```
if i >= len(str):
    return 0
```

I'd also double check if returning zero is what you want to do there. If you find a capital letter, you're returning it from your other conditional case. It's not always ideal to return different types in different situations, as it can be tricky for the caller to know what APIs they can use on the result. Returning an empty string, or `None` might make more sense than returning a number.

Comment: Wow thank. you for your very detailed explanation , What would be the better way to approach this with reference to "return different types in different situations" how can I improve this code to be more reliable

Comment: Returning `None` would be more traditional for when you need a "sentinel" value to signal an unusual situation. Just change the `if (res == 0):` check in the calling code to `if res is None:`. But also consider that raising an exception (with an appropriate type and an error message inside of it) might be a better still. It's sometimes easier to catch exceptions than deal with special values, depending on the structure of the code. You can let an exception "bubble" out of several levels of nesting before you catch it, and it can be harder to do that manually.

Answer (score 2):

`str[i]` will raise this `index out of range` exception if `i` is greater or equal to the length of `str`. You should change your base case to:

```
if (i >= len(str)):
    return 0
```

Comment: Those brackets `(` and `)` are redundant.

Comment: You can edit them out if you wish, but I chose to keep the style of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

using str[i]==None will 'force' python to determine the value of str[i], which doesn't exist, thus the index out of range error. You can determine that you reached the end of the string using len(str) and i instead:

```
def firstCapital(str, i):
    if i>len(str)-1: #Instead of str[i]==None
       return 0
    if str[i].isupper():
        return str[i]
return firstCapital(str, i + 1)

input : ('Ali',0) 
Output: 'A'

Input: ('lia',0) 
Output:0
```